# Unstable ssh connections in to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sshd, timeout

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Server as my web host and mac os x as my work machine.
I have troubles while connecting to host by ssh
Sometimes i can ssh successfully and fast, but sometimes it says connection timed out.
Best reproduction of this error:
I make `ssh -v myhost.com` and it quickly connects.
 Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close connection and it closes.
 Then I try to connect again with the same command and get "connection timed out" message. 
Popular solution with "UseDNS no" dont work :(

Comment: It sounds like either the network connection to the server is not consistant or the service is not responding consistently.  Test the network connection by running `ping -c1000 myHost.com` and see if it has 0.0% packet loss.  If it has no packet loss, leave an ssh session open on the server and try to connect from another terminal/putty windows and see if anything shows in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ssh` port to be different then `22` - this solution worked for me some time ago.